# Tools used to update dynamic properties without even restarting the application/server

Tags: apache, unix, hadoop, apache-zookeeper, jboss6.x

In my project I am trying to do the setting where in I can update the dynamic properties in the server/application without even restarting it.

We face this problem that whenever we have to update or change some properties which are dynamic in nature, then every time we have to restart the server/application and this results in unavailability of the server for that time stamp.

I have already found one tool **Archaius-ZooKeeper** to set it.https://github.com/Netflix/archaius/

We are trying to do it for JBoss servers where we use war file to deploy on server.

**Please suggest are there any other method or tool or technology that can be used to set it**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider [jRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/), allows you to redeploy your app without any downtime, then you can use [jRebel Remoting](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/learn/remoting/eclipse/) to redeploy from eclipse to a remote server

Answer (score 0):

You may use Zookeeper. You have to create a Znode and add the properties in the Znode. All your servers/applications should read from this Znode and also put an watch on this Znode for data changes.

Alternately, you may use a database to store the properties along with their modification time. Whenever you change the value of a property, the corresponding modification time is changed. All your applications/servers keep pulling the delta at some intervals (may be 2 secs/ 5 secs etc.).

Or you may have the properties hosted on a web server, or on NFS, or on some distributed cache etc. All your applications/servers keep reading it at some intervals for detecting any changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Spring Cloud Zookeeper](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-zookeeper). I shared a little example [here](http://therore.net/distributed-configuration-with-zookeeper-curator-and-spring-cloud-config/).